# Query to display employee names, dept no and highest salary in dept no wise

Tags: sql-server

I need a query to display employee names, dept no and highest salary in dept no wise

Example

```
ENAME   SAL    dept no
KING    5000    10
FORD    3000    20
SCOTT   3000    20
BLAKE   2850    30
```

Comment: Hi Kalleshi - When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck, this will ensure there is enough context for stackoverflow'rs to assist you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter said, it's helpful when you provide more detail about what you've tried.

Nonetheless, I think  you're looking for something like this:

```
;with cte as (
    select ename, sal, [dept no]
        , row_number() over (partition by [dept no] order by sal desc, ename) rn
    from your_table
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Note that your example data shows the same SAL of 3000 for [dept no] 20.  To *attempt* to break ties, I added the `ename` to the `order by` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This query displays correctly

```
select ENAME, SAL, [deptno]
from (
    select *
        , DENSE_RANK() over(partition by [deptno] order by sal desc) as Highest_sal
    from Employee
) a
where a.Highest_sal = 1
```